# ClearCase Cleartool wants 32-bit libncurses.so.5 on Centos 7

Tags: centos, libraries, 32-bit

I am trying to get Clearcase's Cleartool to run in a Docker container and everything seems to go well until it says it cannot find libncurses.so.5. The library is there but the problem appears to be that Cleartool wants the 32-bit version. I am unable to find a 32-bit version of the ncurses libraries for Centos 7, the container image I am authorized to use for this particular task. How I get those 32-bit libraries?